# Login with Amazon and popup = false fails when getting token

Tags: login-with-amazon

We've been using LWA for a while successfully. We currently use the following options for "authorize":

- scope: 'profile'
- response_type: 'code'
- popup: true

We use a redirect_uri instead of a callback function.
On the server we then request a token using the response code. All this worked without problems.

We now want to change from using a popup to a redirect to a separate page.

I switched popup to false, and updated the "return urls" on the LWA dashboard. Tthe sign in seems to work well, but once our "return_uri" is called, we fail to get the oauth token (we get 400 Bad Request) back.

From reading the [docs](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/lwa/dev/docs/website-developer-guide._TTH_.pdf), I can't figure out what else I have to change. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it while rereading the docs. I needed to include a redirect_uri in when requesting the token from the backend. (And it should match the one used when calling authorize in JS SDK.)

**Note:** This is mentioned in the table of parameters, but the example is wrong and doesn't include it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution.